# get all elements in a loop through xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am currently learning selenium using python

html is:

```
<ol class="item-section">
<li>
   <div class="abc xyz">
           <div class="foo qwe">
                 <a href="/watch123"></a>
           </div>
   </div>           
</li>
<li>
     <div class="abc xyz">
           <div class="foo qwe">
                 <a href="/watch456"></a>
           </div>
   </div>
</li>
<li>
     <div class="abc xyz">
           <div class="foo qwe">
                 <a href="/watch678"></a>
           </div>
   </div>
</li>
</ol>
```

I want to get all hrefs from the list, through xpath
I tried

```
html_list = driver.find_element_by_class_name("item-section")
    items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
    stack=[]
    index = 1
    for item in items:
        index+=1
        link = item.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='foo qwe']["+index+"]/a")
        print (index,"--->  ",link.get_attribute("href"))
```

but it gives error `Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly` 
If I just use

```
link = item.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='foo qwe']/a")
```

I get the first href multiple times

Comment: why dont you go for `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='foo qwe']/a")`

Comment: Thanks!! it worked

Comment: @Madhan you need to post it as answer and OP should accept it as answer....thanks

Comment: You were getting the error because you were trying to implicitly cast an int as a string. `"//div[@class='foo qwe']["+index+"]/a"` would have worked (or at least not thrown that error) if you had explicitly cast `index` to a string: `"//div[@class='foo qwe']["+str(index)+"]/a"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of elements using

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='foo qwe']/a")

or

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
inputs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='foo qwe']/a")
```